# Export 2007 workflows for display

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, export, visio

I need to export my SharePoint Designer 2007 workflows so I can show people how they work/what the conditions are.

I found a similar question [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-import-and-export-sharepoint-workflows-in-visio-HA101888007.aspx#_Toc265226191) but I have Visio Standard 2007 and this is for 2010 so I do not have the menu options required.

So I need either

1. Instructions how to export/import in 2007
2. Another way of exporting the workflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not found a solution so I don't think there is a way of exporting/displaying them visually. If you find one let me know!

Answer (score 1):

In below link it says that Export to Visio 2007 is not possible in SharePoint 2007.

http://mrin17.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/comparison-between-sharepoint-designer-2007-and-2010/

Comment: Ah that's annoying, is there another way to display the workflows visually?